# OpenGL attribute offset not working as intended

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I am trying to figure out why the offset value used in `glVertexAttribPointer` isn't working as I expect it to.

The code is available at http://glbase.codeplex.com/

My vertex data is this :

```
glBase::Vector3 data1[]={
    glBase::Vector3(-0.4f,0.8f,-0.0f),  //Position
    glBase::Vector3(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f),    //Color
    glBase::Vector3(-.8f,-0.8f,-0.0f),  //Position etc
    glBase::Vector3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f),
    glBase::Vector3(0.0f,-0.8f,-0.0f),
    glBase::Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f)
};
```

And the attribute binding happens like this :

```
program.bindVertexAttribs<float>(vbo1,0, "in_Position", 3, 6, 0);
program.bindVertexAttribs<float>(vbo1,1, "in_Color", 3, 6, 12);
```

bindVertexAttribs function is defined as follows :

```
template<typename T>
void bindVertexAttribs(const VertexBufferObject& object, GLint location,const std::string& name, unsigned int width, unsigned int stride, unsigned int offset)
{
    object.bind();

    glBindAttribLocation(m_ID, location, name.c_str());

    glVertexAttribPointer(location, width, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride*sizeof(T),(GLvoid *)offset);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(location);
}
```

This code doesn't render properly on my machine(ATI 5850,12.10 drivers) and renders the following :

[image]

If I change the attribute binding to :

```
program.bindVertexAttribs<float>(vbo1,0, "in_Position", 3, 6, 12);
program.bindVertexAttribs<float>(vbo1,1, "in_Color", 3, 6, 0);
```

I get the correct render like this :

[image]

This doesn't make sense to me as the position is the first 3 floats in the data array and color is the next 3 floats, then position again and so on. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Please stop using this glBase "library". It's abandoned code that hasn't been touched in *three years*. And any renderer that sticks the rendering function in the *program object* should never be used by anyone to do anything of value. It was junk even when it was *current*; it's not wine, it doesn't get better with age. Trust me: you do not need a C++ wrapper for OpenGL *that badly*.

Comment: I was one of the devs who used to work on it. I recently came back to it and trying to update it.

Comment: Oh. Good; please uncouple mesh state (ie: [Vertex Specification](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Vertex Rendering](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering) ) from programs. Meshes and mesh rendering should be independent of programs.

Comment: Yeah the drawArrays in the shader program was just temporary. It will go into a renderer class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glBindAttribLocation(m_ID, location, name.c_str());
```

This does nothing; feel free to remove this line to see how much nothing it does.

If `m_ID` is a linked program object (and if it's not, then your code makes even less sense. Not unless you're using a VAO to capture your attribute array state), then this function will have no real effect. `glBindAttribLocation` only works *before linking*. You can't change the attribute binding after you link. So every object that uses a program needs to use the *same* attributes.

You should [establish a proper convention for your vertex attribute names.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705924/glsl-uniform-locations-in-glsl-1-2-and-depth-testing-in-shaders/11712816#11712816) When you create any program, you should apply your convention to the program before linking. That way, you know that `in_position` is always attribute 0, for example. You won't have to look it up with a pointless `glGetAttribLocation` call. And you won't be tempted to do the thing you're doing here, which doesn't work.

Comment: m_ID is a linked program object. `glBindAttribLocation only works before linking` this was the problem. The program object was linked and then the bind was called. Thanks!

Comment: removing glBindAttribLocation causes the second screenshot. Did you mean it does nothing when it's called after link or in general?

Comment: @BarışUşaklı: From my answer: "glBindAttribLocation only works before linking."

Comment: The part that confused me was `glBindAttribLocation(m_ID, location, name.c_str());
This does nothing; feel free to remove this line to see how much nothing it does.` It sounded like I don't need that at all. I think you meant it does nothing after program is linked.